# Saving text on a transparent background leaves a white border when uploaded to web... why?

Tags: fonts, photoshop

I need to save a logo with a transparent background.  It looks fine in photoshop, but when I put it onto the site, some lettering has a white border, how do I stop this ?
I have tried "saving for web" as png & gif...!

In photoshop (before I remove the background colour) : [image]

And as it appears on the site :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are saving the image with a transparent background, and the text you have there is antialiased.  This means there is a semi-transparent border around the whole thing.  Looks great on a like-colored background, but is really obvious when shown on a darker background.

You need to redo your text block in PhotoShop as an actual font.  Right now it's rendered and anti-aliased, and that's your problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `an actual font`?

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I removed the font setting 'Smooth' (the other options are crisp, sharp & strong) and set the option to 'none' This removed the anti-aliasing :)

Comment: @Mark - yes.  In Photoshop, when you create a text block, it is unrendered, and vector based - it uses the actual font map.  So you don't get that antialiasing.  It's not until you "merge down" or otherwise render the layer to a bitmap, that you get that undesired effect.  In the case of this post, it appears that that text was a rendered bitmap with a background which was removed using the selection tool, and it left a residual border from the old background.  That's why I suggested recreating it.

Comment: @durbnpoisn - actually, I used the font tool and created it from scratch - it was the "smooth" setting that was creating the anti-aliasing effect - but your answer still solved my problem !

Comment: Cool.  Needless to say, I knew exactly what happened as soon as I saw it.  I just provided more explanation as to why it happens at all.

Comment: Another thing you might consider.  Save your image as a PNG-24.  Then you can actually USE that smoothness.  The antialiasing is a true semi-transparent.  So you can use it on any background, and it will blend right in.

Comment: @durbnpoisn - You sir, are a star !